# Android: Moving an ImageView from updating Values in a Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to make the ImageView missile1 to spawn at a random y-coordinate on the right edge of the screen and then move it left across the screen until it is off the screen, and finally move it back to a random y-coordinate on the right edge of the screen to repeat the process in an infinite loop. The code I have spawns the image at a totally random x and y coordinate location whenever the activity is restarted, but it doesn't move. Can anybody see why it doesn't move and give a solution to my problem? Some example code will be appreciated.

The thread that generates x and y coordinate values:

```
public class Missiles extends Thread {

    private int height, width, currentscore;
    private ImageView missile1, missile2, missile3, missile4, missile5;
    Handler updatemissile = new Handler();
    int min = 100;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    int setx1, sety1, setx2, sety2, setx3, sety3, setx4, sety4, setx5, sety5;
    private Random rand = new Random();


    TextView x, y;


    Missiles(int screenheight, int screenwidth, ImageView missile01, ImageView missile02, ImageView missile03,
             ImageView missile04, ImageView missile05, RelativeLayout rl, TextView xtext, TextView ytext) {

        missile1 = missile01;
        missile2 = missile02;
        missile3 = missile03;
        missile4 = missile04;
        missile5 = missile05;

        height = screenheight;
        width = screenwidth;
        layout = rl;

        x = xtext;
        y = ytext;

    }

    public void updatevalue(int value) {

        currentscore = value;
    }


    public void run() {

        SetMissilePosition position = new SetMissilePosition(missile1, layout, x, y);
        updatemissile.post(position);

        //width is the width of the screen as height is the height of the screen
        while (true) {
            setx1 = width;
            position.updateX(setx1);

            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((height - min) + 1) + min;

            sety1 = randomNum;
            position.updateY(sety1);

            while (setx1 > -50) {
                setx1 = setx1 - 1;
                position.updateX(setx1);
            }

            setx1 = width;
            position.updateX(setx1);

        }
    }

}
```

The Runnable Class:

```
public class SetMissilePosition implements Runnable{

    int x1,y1, updateindicator;
    ImageView missile1;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    TextView x,y;

    SetMissilePosition(ImageView missile01, RelativeLayout relativeLayout, TextView xtext, TextView ytext) {
        missile1 = missile01;
        layout = relativeLayout;
        x = xtext;
        y = ytext;

    }

    public void updateX( int setx1) {
        x1 = setx1;
        updateindicator = 1;

    }

    public void updateY(int sety1) {
        y1 = sety1;
        updateindicator = 1;
    }

    public void run() {

        missile1.setImageResource(R.drawable.missileanim);
        layout.addView(missile1);

        if(updateindicator == 1) {
            missile1.setX(x1);
            missile1.setY(y1);
            x.setText(Integer.toString(x1));
            y.setText(Integer.toString(y1));
            updateindicator = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If I am being unclear in any way or you need more code such as my MainActivity, please ask. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself through lots of trial end error. What I did was Created an activity that extended surface view, added a bitmap to it, updated the images coordinates in a thread, and finally passed the coordinates into another thread which updated the screen 30 times a second.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to update the UI thread from off of the UI thread.

If that's the route you want to go, I'd encourage you to take a look at the 'run on ui thread' operation. Essentially, when you want to update layout positions, you can just call `getContext().runOnUiThread([runnable])` and that will update your position. See here for more information: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html Some things to bear in mind:

Android runs at 60fps, so you need to make sure you're updating every 16ms or so in order to match in sync with your framerate. Otherwise your speed will be off.

Instead of doing that, why not use a Translate animation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

You can set starting and ending x and y coordinates, you can even use them as percentages of screenwidth and length, and set the animation to repeat infinitely. If repeating infinitely won't work because you want to pick new X (or Y) values each time, you can hook something up on the end of the animation to pick new values and restart.

Comment: About translate animations,  is it possible to detect Imageview collisions during the transformation? I believe this is not possible so I cant use that. I will look into runOnUiThread. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's strictly possible to detect imageview collisions during the transformation, but that shouldn't be a problem. When you initialize the transformation animations, you know what the starting and ending points (and also the speed of the objects moving) are. At that point, the paths are entirely deterministic--so you can just determine if it'll happen ahead of time.

Comment: My application requires real time player input that cant be estimated.

Comment: translate animations are not an option.

Comment: Yeah, then in that case I'd try `runOnUIThread` when you actually have a game state update. That way you can do all of your logic off of the UI thread, and just update the positions of your views on the thread, as needed.